# Get text from edit text and display in textview as paragraph

Tags: android

I need to get the text from edit text to textview. As user type's a word press a button. Again user will type other word. But edit text is replacing the previous word. I need it as a paragraph.

I have tried to store using string builder method.

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ed1));
                String line;
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }


                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                //You'll need to add proper error handling here
            }
```

I want the text view to get edit text input as a paragraph. Even when user type it sentence by sentence.

Comment: what is `ed1` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String inputString = "";  // Before the buttonClick

b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     if(""+ed1.getText().toString().length > 0){

        if(inputString .length() > 0 )
           inputString = inputString +"\n\t"+ ed1.getText().toString();
        else
           inputString = "\t"+ed1.getText().toString();

        txtView.setText(inputString);  // to show data on textView
        ed1.setText("");
     }
   }
 });

 // when user enter data and click buton then entered data will be displayed on TextView in a Paragraph style.
```